# Cascading Two Routers - Wifi Has Issues On 2nd Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

There are plenty of places for tutorials on setting up cascaded routers. I am using the LAN-LAN connection (router 1 - 192.168.1.1 ether cable in a #port, router 2 - 192.168.1.2, ether cable in #1port).

The first router is in the main house. I'm setting this up in the detached garage. The garage router works fine for all hard wired connections. But the wifi will not let any device to fully connect (like if you are on an iOS device, it just spins forever). I have DHCP off on the 2nd router; not sure what else I need to do.

My Workaround: I have tried the following 3 setups **on the wifi devices**. Only the third works.

1. Manually set IP, Subnet, Router on device, left DNS to be AUTO. FAILURE.
2. Leave IP on AUTO, manually set DNS (I enter the two servers I see on my iMac's DNS tab). FAILURE.
3. Manually set IP, Subnet, Router AND DNS (both servers). This solution allows me to connect fully and have access to the internet.

DHCP is ON for router 1, DHCP is OFF for router 2. Wired and wireless connections work on router 1. Router 2, only wired works automatically, wireless requires manual intervention.

Question: What settings am I missing so that router 2's wifi connections do not need manual intervention to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If wired connections work, wireless connection absolutely should work, too. Maybe the radio is broken.

Comment: compare `$ ip route` on a "working" computer to the same from a "nonworking" one. Most importantly, there should be a line saying something similar to `default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp metric 100` in both, e.g. with that IP being equal in them.

Comment: Does your wireless connection have "Wireless Isolation" enabled?  If so, disable it.   Also, this is not cascading routers - you are turning one of the routers into a switch + AP, there is no routing.

Comment: DanielB - *Shrugs* when it's factory reset, wireless connections work fine w/o intervention.

Hannu - I'll have to look into this. I don't know how to check this - I'm still quite novice.

Davidgo - I don't see any "isolation" option on the router. And not to argue as I'm sure you're correct but the online tutorials for cascading have this setup I'm following and Lan-Wan. So, not sure what else to call it if it isn't cascading. The Lan-Wan (changing the second routers IP to 192.168.**2**.1 and #port from router 1 to Internet port of 2nd router). Never worked - even for wired connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reset both routers to factory settings.
2. Check you have internet on main router. Check wifi and ethernet.
3. Turn OFF dhcp on second router.
4. set IP of second router one above first router. If first router 192.168.1.1, then set LAN ip of second router 192.168.1.2.
5. Place long cable between routers going to LAN ports on both.
6. set wifi on second router the same SSID & Password of first router.
7. This configuration should work fine as long as DHCP off on second router.

Comment: This is the setup I am using and wireless is not working without the manual intervention described in my OP.

Comment: You need to tell me the model of the second router

Comment: also, your description of the problem is difficult to work out - When you say manual intervention - do you mean setting the IP manually on the computer you are using or the router?

Comment: UPDATE: Linksys e1200. I set this up Sat night (11/12). I had 3 iOS devices that would not connect (just spin). In order to connect, I had to set the IP, subnet, router and DNS on all three devices to connect. We were gone all day 11/13. This AM 11/14, I found my wifes macbook pro connected w/o issue. Thought that was odd and not what I expected to experience, but thankful! I then "forget network" on my two iOS devices, tried to connect automatically without manually setting anything. Both are connecting fine. SO, w/e the issue was, now it's gone and things are working correctly.

Comment: Good work! Glad it was something simple.